# Is nginx server called a forward proxy when used with react

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, proxy

Just trying to clarify some terminology here. When I use nginx to serve a Django API, the nginx server is called a reverse proxy. When I use nginx to serve a React application, is the nginx server called a forward proxy, or is it called something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your are building your react app and hosting the static files on NGINX, NGINX is a Webserver. A Forward-Proxy will be used in Networks for complety different things.

In case you are hosting your react app with NGINX as a webserver and proxy a request through another NGINX Server NGINX is proxying the traffic as a reverse proxy to your target backend webserver.

I hope that makes it clear.